# run matlab script from command line or shell

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to run matlab code from command line or linux shell? If yes, please also let me know what OS you are using. I searched online and found several 'answer' but does not work under my desktop (win 7).

I tried following code in cmd `matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -nojvm -r "a=[3,4,5,6,6]; dlmwrite('test', a);"`. Although the code worked and write out the file under current folder, but there is this white backgrounded window open up. Can it just run quietly and when finished, do not show this window?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call matlab from command prompt. In a windows machine it will look like this depending on your matlab installation path:

```
"C:\Path\to\matlab\matlab.exe" -r matfile.m
```

But it does open up Matlab gui. I do not know how to run it silently, but including

```
exit
```

at the end of your routine will close it automatically.

Comment: how about in other OS, like linux, for example, some server is purely based on command line, there are no GUI at all. There is no way this while background command line will show up, right?

Comment: I am not sure if the same behavior would occur in a linux machine. I cannot get my hands into a linux OS atm to try it out. If it remains unanswered I can check this out later

Comment: In linux, you still need `-nosplash -nodisplay` to hide the main window.